# Uppercase module names - what could go wrong, technically?

Tags: 8

This is a technical curiosity question.

Afaik, it is convention that module names in Drupal should be lowercase, with underscores.

Obviously it is generally good to follow conventions.

But does someone know what could go wrong, technically, if module names are upper case or mixed case? E.g. camel case.

I think to remember to have seen at least one case in contrib where a module was CamelCase, but I don't remember which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update functions, for example, go wrong: The regular expression that looks for them only works if the module name is lowercase only.

I don't remember exactly how it fails, but I used to have a case once where someone wrote a module that had uppercase characters and it wasn't possible to have update functions.

That's the only thing that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks! Let's see what others come up with, and if not I accept this one :)